# A doubt about a proof of chain rule for smooth functions between smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, smooth-manifolds, chain-rule

I'm reading Theorem 1.1 in [this](https://minterscompactness.files.wordpress.com/2019/01/Differential_Geometry_Part_II_Notes.pdf) lecture notes.

---

**Theorem 1.1** (Chain Rule for Manifolds). Suppose $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $g: Y \rightarrow Z$ are smooth maps of manifolds. Then:
$$
\mathrm{d}(g \circ f)_{x}=(\mathrm{d} g)_{f(x)} \circ(\mathrm{d} f)_{x}
$$

*Proof.* If $\varphi$ is a local parameterisation of $x, \psi$ is a local parameterisation of $y=f(x)$, and $\eta$ is a local parameterisation of $z=g(f(x))$, then this is evident from:
$$
g \circ f=\left[\eta \circ\left(\eta^{-1} \circ g \circ \psi\right) \circ \psi^{-1}\right] \circ\left[\psi \circ\left(\psi^{-1} \circ f \circ \varphi\right) \circ \varphi^{-1}\right]
$$
and the usual chain rule from multivariate analysis (as we can differentiate the RHS as before using the usual chain rule).

[image]

---

In the proof, $g \circ f = \Psi \circ \Phi$ with \begin{align}
\Psi &:= \eta \circ\left(\eta^{-1} \circ g \circ \psi\right) \circ \psi^{-1} \\
\Phi &:= \psi \circ\left(\psi^{-1} \circ f \circ \varphi\right) \circ \varphi^{-1}.
\end{align}

The composition of smooth maps is also smooth, so $\Psi, \Phi$ are smooth. However, $\operatorname{dom} (\Psi) = \operatorname{dom} (\psi^{-1})$ which is open in $Y$ but not necessarily open in its ambient Euclidean space. The same situation holds for $\Phi$. So $\Psi, \Phi$ are not differentiable in the usual sense, so we can not apply the chain rule on $\Psi \circ \Phi$. However, the author said

> "...we can differentiate the RHS as before using the usual chain rule...".

Could you please elaborate on my confusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In definition 1.8 of the lecture notes, it is said that if $f\colon X \to Y$ is smooth and if $\varphi \colon U \to X$ and $\psi \colon V \to Y$ are local parametrisations in neighbourhoods of $x$ and $f(x)$, then

$$
df_x = d\psi_{\psi^{-1}(f(x))} \circ d(\psi^{-1}\circ f \circ \varphi)_{\varphi^{-1}(x)} \circ \big[(d\varphi_{\varphi^{-1}(x)})^{-1} \big]
$$
where $d\varphi_{\varphi^{-1}(x)}$ is considered as an isomorphism from $\Bbb R^n \to T_xX$, that is, forgeting about the ambiant euclidean space $\Bbb R^N$ around $X$.

Same thing with $g$ at the point $f(x)$ gives
$$
dg_{f(x)} = d\eta_{\eta^{-1}(g(f(x)))} \circ d(\eta^{-1}\circ g \circ \psi)_{\psi^{-1}(f(x))} \circ \big[(d\psi_{\psi^{-1}(f(x))})^{-1} \big]
$$
where $d\psi_{\psi^{-1}(f(x))}$ is considered as an isomiorphism from $\Bbb R^{\tilde{n}} \to T_{f(x)}Y$, that is, forgeting about the ambiant euclidean space $\Bbb R^{\tilde{N}}$ around $Y$.

For $g\circ f$, it yields
$$
d(g\circ f)_{g(f(x))} = d\eta_{\eta^{-1}(g(f(x)))} \circ d(\eta^{-1}\circ (g\circ f) \circ \varphi)_{\varphi^{-1}(x)} \circ \big[(d\varphi_{\varphi^{-1}(x)})^{-1} \big]
$$

You are thus lead to show that
$$
d(\eta^{-1}\circ (g\circ f) \circ \varphi)_{\varphi^{-1}(x)}= \big(d(\eta^{-1}\circ g \circ \psi)_{\psi^{-1}(f(x))}\big)\circ\big( d(\psi^{-1}\circ f \circ \varphi)_{\varphi^{-1}(x)}\big)
$$

This is just the chain-rule applied to the composition of

$$
\psi^{-1}\circ f \circ \varphi \colon U \subset \Bbb R^n \to V \subset \Bbb R^{\tilde{n}}  
$$
and
$$
\eta^{-1}\circ g\circ \psi \colon V \subset \Bbb R^{\tilde{n}} \to W \subset \Bbb R^{\tilde{\tilde{n}}}
$$
which are smooth functions defined on and with range in open subsets of euclidean spaces.

**By the way:** there is an obvious typo in the author's sketch: the arrow of at bottom right corner should be $\eta^{-1}\circ g \circ \psi$, not $\eta^{-1}\circ f \circ \psi$.

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood the author's ideas. He meant to apply chain rule on $\psi^{-1}\circ f \circ \varphi$ and on $\eta^{-1}\circ g\circ \psi$ separately, not on $\Psi \circ \Phi$. Thank you so much!

Comment: Not exactly on $\varphi^{-1}\circ f \circ \varphi$ and $\eta^{-1}\circ g \circ \psi$ separatly, but on the composition $(\eta^{-1}\circ g \circ \psi)\circ (\psi^{-1}\circ g \circ \varphi)$!

Comment: Hi Didier, I'm quite unsure if my proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4316048/inverse-function-theorem-on-smooth-manifolds) contains subtle logical mistakes. Could you please have a check on it?